# Why was The Secrets of Isis cancelled?

Tags: cancellation, the-secrets-of-isis

The 1970s superhero TV show, [Secrets of Isis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secrets_of_Isis), was cancelled after two years. According to the Wikipedia page it was popular. Why was it cancelled?

Comment: Obviously it wasn't popular enough.

Comment: I don't think that 40+ years ago there was much "behind the scenes"-reporting on such reasons.

Comment: Plus the word "popular" does not appear anywhere on the Wikiepedia page

Comment: @Paulie_D It says "The success of the show led to syndication of the series"

Comment: Syndication is not the same popular although there may be a correlation...but I'll revise to "not successful enough".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The show was got canceled due to low ratings.

As mentioned [here](http://screenrant.com/most-obscure-tv-superheroes/):

> The Secrets of Isis was quite possibly the first American live-action
>   TV series about a female superhero – predating both Wonder Woman and
>   Bionic Woman. It debuted on CBS in September of 1975. All in all, two
>   seasons and 22 episodes of The Secrets of Isis aired before the show
>   got canceled due to low ratings.